# Hover an element and affect another with the same parent

Tags: css, hover

I know it's a question asked tons of times, but I'm not able to find my answer.

I have a container with 2 divs

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">three, please hover me</div>
    </div>
    <div id="one">one</div>
</div>
```

where `#one` is shown outside the container with an absolute positioning, and `#two` is a container to let div `#three` to float right.

I would like to show `#one` when hovering `#three`. Basing on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered), I have tried to add a `+` selector in my code, since `#one` is directly after the `#two` closing tag, but it doesn't work ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jPKKY/)).

You can change my structure if needed, the only things that I would like to keep are that `#one` is shown outside the container and `#two` is floated to right. If possible, I would like to avoid using jQuery scripts and keep everything in CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Is this acceptable: http://jsfiddle.net/jPKKY/1/

Comment: @ExplosionPills unfortunately not, since I have other elements within `#two` and `#one` should be shown when only hovering `#three`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're asking then because there is no way to select ancestors in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked your fiddle and changed it around a little to do what you require. Let me know if that's what you're after. When I'm not at work and have a bit more time, I can explain what's happening.

The key is moving your `div#one` into the same container as the `:hover`

http://jsfiddle.net/bWb3Q/

EDIT: based on comments on question, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bWb3Q/3/

Comment: Yes, this does the trick! I didn't try this way because I thought that the `overflow:hidden` property would have hidden `#one`. Thanks!